# Is there a way to mock generically with Mockito Java

Tags: java, junit, mockito, twilio

I'm currently working on a Twilio Api implementation here.
Some of my main service methods need to call a Room.fetcher() method provided by their api.
For exemple:

```
    private Room getRoomInfo(String roomSid) {
        Room room = Room.fetcher(roomSid)).fetch();
        return room;
    }
```

As it's impossible for us to request the real service every time we run the test suite, I need to mock this return.

I know this approach of mocking (works pretty well with the rest of the code):

```
  @Before
      public void setupMockedRespositoryCalls() {
      Mockito.when(exempleRepository
                .findByName("fakeName"))
                .thenReturn(Optional.of(new MyFixtureClass));
      ...
  }
```

Well, we use this class Room here in our application, but it's too big to construct manually.
My idea was using a shorter version of this class just with what we need not to have to instantiate a huge class as a fixture.

Of course it didn't work and gave me **The method thenReturn(Room) in the type OngoingStubbing is not applicable for the arguments (fakeReducedRoomObject)**

**Is there a way of mocking another type into this object?**

```
    @Before
    public void setupFakeFinishedTwilioRoom() {
        Mockito.when(Room.fetcher("exampleRoomSid").fetch())
        .thenReturn(fakeReducedRoomObject);
    }
```

I know it's a Java thing, not Mockito's, but I'd like to know if you guys know any workarounds.
Thanks!

Comment: Workaround: mock whatever instance is returned by `Room.fetcher("exampleRoomSid")`, set up `Room.fetcher(...)` to return that mock. Configure that mock to return the `fakeReducedRoomObject` when `fetch()` is called. Verbose, but necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Guess that's the only way really. Trying this right now!